# traversing li of each mentioned ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is a simple code-

```js
var ulreq = $("#abc").children("ul.ghi");
var lists = ulreq.find("li");
for( var i = 0; i < lists.length; ++i){
 alert(lists[i].text());
 //show show the values in these li
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
 <ul class="def">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="ghi">
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="lkj">
 <ul class="def">
  <li>g</li>
  <li>h</li>
  <li>i</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="ghi">
  <li>j</li>
  <li>k</li>
  <li>l</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

it should pop up
d
e
f
I am not getting where i am going wrong..please check
thanx in advance.

sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: whats with all the `sssssssssssssss`?

Comment: Did you bother to try to run your snippet to make sure it runs? Because it doesn't.

Comment: @Iceman minimum words constraint

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes..this is a part of the actual code of my work

Comment: Run the snippet and look at the full output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
alert(lists[i].text());
```

When you index into a jQuery object, you're accessing a raw DOM element. Raw DOM elements don't have a `text` method. That's what your browser was telling you when it said:

> `Uncaught TypeError: lists[i].text is not a function`

You either want

```
alert($(lists[i]).text());
```

or

```
alert(lists.eq(i).text());
```

Here's the latter one:

```js
var ulreq = $("#abc").children("ul.ghi");
var lists = ulreq.find("li");
for( var i = 0; i < lists.length; ++i){
 alert(lists.eq(i).text());
 //show show the values in these li
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
 <ul class="def">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="ghi">
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="lkj">
 <ul class="def">
  <li>g</li>
  <li>h</li>
  <li>i</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="ghi">
  <li>j</li>
  <li>k</li>
  <li>l</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad..could not concentrate on the brackets.Thnx